# ROS Installation for NXT

Tags: nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Here is my question. If I have already installed ros-electric-desktop-full in my desktop, and if I want to work on NXT with ROS, how should I configure it? Can the steps mentioned in "http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/electric" be executed even if I have already installed ros-electric-desktop-full?

Thanks in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11340/ros-installation-for-nxt/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You need to take steps described in "http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/electric"

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-09-28**:
Thank you Alexandr!